# Only one checkbox checked and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have small problem with checkboxes. Better way to do that is radio button but I must do that with checkboxes.

Here's the code:

```
$('input.box1').not(this).prop('checked', false).val("N");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SwmN6/154/)

and it's working because one of checkboxes is checked. But in input value is "true" for this two checkboxes. How Can I change that code to do that when I check checkbox other should have a "false" value.

I try something like this:

```
$('input.box1').on('change', function() {
        $('input.box1').not(this).prop('checked', false).val("N");
        $('input.box1').this.prop('checked', true).val("T");
});
```

but didn't work

-What I expect?
1.In example click first checkbox - value of that checkbox is "T" the second checkbox has value  "N"
2. Click second checkbox - value of that checkbox is "T" the first checkbox has value  "N"

Comment: your fiddle and code doesn't match. so update your fiddle

Comment: what's your server side language?

Comment: Your code working now? I see in DEMO and found that your code is wrong at the first launch with the number of checkbox greater than 2.

Comment: If you want to use checkboxes in same way as  radio buttons (i mean only one checked at a time and once checked you cannot uncheck using mouse click) use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/4pwep76j/3/). fiddle is updated code of `Milind Anantwar`

Comment: It's correct but in my case I can have both checkboxes "unchecked"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have error in your code at line `$('input.box1').this.prop('checked', 
true).val("T");`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined

That's because `$('input.box1').this` is undefined. SYNTAX ERROR.

Correct way to do this is simply using context `this` in change function :

```
$('input.box1').on('change', function() {
        $('input.box1').not(this).prop('checked', false).val("N");
        $(this).val(this.checked?'Y':'N');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uqgr84a7/)**

Comment: @Adamo: glad it helps :)

Comment: Your code is wrong at the first launch with the number of checkboxes greater than 2. All checkboxes except the first will be checked.

Comment: Both of you, bro ^^ @Adamo [Milind code](http://jsfiddle.net/4pwep76j/2/), [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/SwmN6/157/)

Comment: @MrNeo: i am sorry. i didn't get you. Could please point to particular line with the issue.

Comment: Yes now I see that. How can I repair this issue?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: you could see on the [jsfiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/4pwep76j/2/). I am a newbie in js, but I think that `$('input.box1').not(this).prop('checked', false)` make all checkboxes checked except the first one.

Comment: @MrNeo: no its not. they are checked because they have attribute checked in them. the js code is only getting called on change.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: Ah, yes, thanks for your explaination ^^

Comment: I like the question and the answer.

Comment: I have small question to you @MilindAnantwar. It is possible to check only on checkbox if i cliked to them. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uqgr84a7/2/ I want on first run to uncheck only one checkbox not both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.box1').this.prop('checked', true).val("T") it throw Uncaught error instead of this u can use $(this).prop('checked', true).val("T")
```

```
(function ($) {
   var count = 0;
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('input.box1').on('change', function(e) {
          $('input.box1').not(this).prop('checked', false).val("N");
          $(this).prop('checked', true).val("T");

          console.log($("#chkBox1").val(), $("#chkBox2").val());
       });
   });
})(jQuery);
```